# Access Array inside Array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I am trying to access `repayments` from the list of arrays below:

```
    Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [account_name] => Loan
            [user_id] => 394822e3-d1ad-4043-8dff-5ef244aaf9e9
            [account_no] => 0333481a3-43cf-4dad-a0d7-715f335b8ff820217196
            [loan_details] => Array
                (
                    [purpose] => Fund for school
                     [description] => Hhh
                    [loan_amount] => 5200
                    [repayment_type] => equal
                    [tenor] => 2
                    [default] => 0.2
                    [repayment_frequency] => monthly
                    [interest_rate] => 4
                    [approved_amount] => 5000
                    [repayments] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Array
                                (
                                    [principal] => 2500
                                    [default_interest_rate] => 0.2
                                    [interest] => 200
                                    [payment_date] => 2022-02-18
                                    [status] => pending
                                )

                            [1] => Array
                                (
                                    [principal] => 2500
                                    [default_interest_rate] => 0.2
                                    [interest] => 200
                                    [payment_date] => 2022-03-20
                                    [status] => pending
                                )

                        )

                    [start_date] => 2022-01-19
                    [status] => active
                )

            [status] => inactive
            [createdAt] => 2021-08-26T22:09:38.268Z
            [id] => 4834d95d-2f0e-434f-bfa4-8fb1c6944ef9
        )

)
```

In my PHP script as follows:

```
$resp = curl_get("",$global_var->base_url."/account/get-account-by-account-type?accountType=loan","get",$global_var->getToken());

$array = json_decode(json_encode($resp->data->accounts), true);

foreach($array as $loan) {
    //Trying to acccess **repayments**
    $loan_details = $loan['loan_details'];
    print_r($loan_details['repayments']);
}
```

Running the script I have the following error

> Notice: Undefined index: repayments in

Could someone tell me how to solve this?

Comment: Look at your array, walk down it to the thing you want, dont forget about the `[0]` entries and all intermediary nodes

Comment: So `$loan_details = $array[0]['load_details'];` and `$repayments = $array[0]['loan_details']['repayments'];`

Comment: So try `foreach($array[0] as $loan) {`

Comment: @RiggsFolly Thanks for ur time. I discovered some users don't have repayment which echoed *Undefined index: repayments*. That's solved. Thanks again